# How can i pre-rendered on the server in Angular Unviersal Project?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am calling apis on the server side using TransferState Module of Angular Universal. And it takes about 6 ~ 7 seconds and the server side rendering is implemented.
So when reload the page, i can see the loaded page after 6 ~ 7 seconds every time. Those apis are being called only on the server when the page is loaded.
How can i pre-render this page on the server so that to improve the loading time?

Comment: Please provide some more details: what API is the Angular Universal server calling? How long do these API requests take? Where are you hosting your Angular Universal application?

Answer (score 0):

You can run prerender based Angular Universal:

[package.json](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/package.json)

```
 "build:prerender": "npm run build:universal && npm run generate:prerender",
 "generate:prerender": "node prerender.js"
```

[prerender.ts](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/prerender.ts)

```
import { environment } from './src/environments/environment';

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
const files = fs.readdirSync(`${process.cwd()}/dist-server`);

global['window'] = win;
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
global['document'] = win.document;
global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global['Prism'] = null;

// Load zone.js for the server.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync, existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ROUTES } from './static.paths';

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const mainFiles = files.filter((file) => file.startsWith('main'));
const hash = mainFiles[0].split('.')[1];
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require(`./dist-server/main.${hash}`);
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

const BROWSER_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'static');

// Load the index.html file containing referances to your application bundle.
const index = readFileSync(join('dist', 'index.html'), 'utf8');

let previousRender = Promise.resolve();

// Iterate each route path
ROUTES.forEach((route) => {
  const fullPath = join(BROWSER_FOLDER, route);

  // Make sure the directory structure is there
  if (!existsSync(fullPath)) {
    let syncpath = BROWSER_FOLDER;
    route.split('/').forEach((element) => {
      syncpath = syncpath + '/' + element;
      mkdirSync(syncpath);
    });
  }

  // Writes rendered HTML to index.html, replacing the file if it already exists.
  previousRender = previousRender
    .then((_) =>
      renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
        document: index,
        url: route,
        extraProviders: [
          provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
          {
            provide: REQUEST,
            useValue: { cookie: '', headers: {} },
          },
          {
            provide: RESPONSE,
            useValue: {},
          },
          {
            provide: 'ORIGIN_URL',
            useValue: environment.host,
          },
        ],
      }),
    )
    .then((html) => writeFileSync(join(fullPath, 'index.html'), html));
});
```

static.paths.ts

```
export const ROUTES = ['/routePrerenderPage', '/home' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to prerender Angular, you need to have these things ready:

1. Pages routes
   if you have two pages such as 'home' and 'contact', then your final project structure should be like this:

```
|---root
|---index.html
|---/home
    |---index.html
|---/contact
    |---index.html
```

2. Rendering Engine
   You need to use render engine to get the index.html files by loop your routes params in Rendering Engine. In Angular, we use `renderModuleFactory()` as the render engine.

You can refer to this post for more details: [Prerender Angular and Host It on AWS S3.](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/prerender-angular-and-deploy-it-as-a-static-website-on-aws-s3-to-make-it-42-times-faster-115fadcf8614)